# Loopback falling back to default datasources.json

Tags: loopbackjs

I have made the datasources.integration.json environment file along with datasources.json file

When I run the command `NODE_ENV=integration node .`

I get an error for a table which is in localhost, which means loopback is falling back to the default datasources.json

I am clueless as to why it is not taking the settings from datasources.integration.json?

Comment: If you try debugging (https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Setting-debug-strings.html) do you see anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, solved it, actually I was making a query request to bring in the constants from a database table, before `app.start()` in *server.js*, which was causing the issue, just moved that block of code after `app.start()` and the issue was resolved. :)